# Excel - how to find duplicates cells ONLY for cells containing specific text

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I've been fiddling with conditional formatting rules in excel for a while and I can't figure this out.

I want to automatically highlight any duplicate cells -- but i only want certain cells to be considered.

So I need excel to only search cells containing this partial text string "<<<", and then tell me which of those is a duplicate by hilighting the cells.

I need all cells which do not contain "<<<" to be ignored.

thx

Comment: Instead of a single condition, try having one that highlights all duplicate cells and another that removes the highlight if "<<<" is not present

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` with 2 criteria

Comment: Using `<<<` as a marker is problematic with `COUNTIFS` (it is interpreted as _Less Than_ ).  Could you change that to some other character?  If you can (eg `###`) then Conditional Format formula is `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,A1,$A:$A,"###*")>1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) will point you in the right direction. I don't think it will fully answer your question but it will help (if you are open to a VBA solution).

**EDIT**

I think this method will work for you.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindDuplicates()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CountOfDuplicate As Long

    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For Each Cell In MyRange
        CountOfDuplicate = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, "=" & Cell)
        If CountOfDuplicate > 1 And InStr(1, Cell, "<<<") > 0 Then
            Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

The above procedure will test each cell in the `CurrentRegion` for the partial string `<<<` and a `CountIfs` result greater than 1 and color the interior of the cells gray. Let me know if this does the trick for you.

Comment: I replaced A1 on your code with the range of my data, and the <<<* dupes were not hilighted in grey.

Comment: Strange. I tested 5 times. Was anything highlighted in gray? Did you get an error message? Did you put the code in a regular module? Are your cells contiguous? It works on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: range is contiguous yes, here's the code I used. and I pasted it on "view code" on my excel sheet tab. I have 2 values i set up as tests in column C -- <<<test1>>> and another <<<test1>>>. I would have expected those to hilight in grey as they are dupes with <<< string. 

here's what I changed:

`Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").CurrentRegion`

Comment: Hmmm. Check to see if your pasted code compiles by clicking `Debug` > `Compile VBAProject`. I put the code in "view code', also, and it still worked. I even used your `<<<test1>>>` example.

Comment: Not sure what to say. Maybe you put the code in the wrong worksheet object? Try adding a module and putting the code there. Then run it from `Developer` > `Macros`. Otherwise, run it from the Visual Basic Editor. The module is where it should be.

Comment: i don't either. I did all you just said...even ran it as a macro. no grey. :( oh well.